# SQL Server Procedure Output CR and LF replaced with Spaces on Copy and Paste

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a curious problem for which I can find nothing on the net and hope someone here can provide some insight:

In a stored procedure, I am traversing a table using a cursor and collating all the values of a single text field (varchar) into a single string variable. Each row I am separating with a Carriage Return / Line Feed (characters 13 and 10).

If I print the variable to the screen, the CR and LF characters are clearly there and in the output in the message window are showing as I would expect by formatting the string into separate lines.

If I check the ASCII values in the string variable at the appropriate positions, the correct ASCII values are showing (13 and 10 respectively)

If I insert the string into a temporary table, I can also see that the CR and LF characters have been retained (by again inspecting the ASCII values in code).

BUT if I 'select' the variable so it appears in a grid and then copy the output and paste into an editor (notepad, word, SQL Query Window etc) the CR and LF have been replaced with spaces.

I don't think this has anything to do with normal Copy/Paste functionality as copying from any other environment retains all the characters. Is there something peculiar to the copy facility when copying a cell in SQL Query Analyser grid output?

While this isn't a show-stopper for me, it does mean I have to jump through some hoops I feel I shouldn't have to - but also, I'm just curious.

Cheers, J

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by the CR and the LF characters being replaced by spaces. How did you see that? CR and LF characters are usually invisible characters. So how did you determine they are being changed?

Comment: That just a problem of the ability of the client grid in handling CR+LF, some can, others not.

Comment: You should include the version of management studio you're using. I'm using 11.0.3128.0 and could not reproduce this problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server Management Studio, use "Results to Text" (Ctrl+T). That should maintain the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If I run this in management studio then copy and paste the resulting cell into notepad it appears correctly:

```
select 'line1' + char(13) + char(10) + 'line2'
```

alternatively you could try this:

```
select 'line1
line2'
```

in case it's a unicode problem you could try using the unicode crlf equivalent:

```
select N'line1' + nchar(0x000D) + N'line2'
```